# ASP.net binding to a property that is an array of custom types

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'll use Customer and Addresses as an example rather than explain my real objects.

Say I have a repeater bound to a collection of Customers and one of the properties of Customer is an array of addresses.  How do I bind to the addresses property?

I don't even need to display this information I just want to use it in the Repeaters ItemDataBound event. So I tried to bind a hiddenField to the addresses property but all I get for every customer in the hiddenfields value is an empty array of addresses.

I suppose what would be ideal is if I could bind the hiddenfield to a string representing the addresses array. (perhaps in JSON format).  How can I do that?  Or has anyone got any better suggestions?

Comment: are you saying that e.Item.DataItem does not contain your child objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Customer c = (Customer)e.Item.DataItem;

    foreach (Address a in c.Addresses)
    {
        //WHEE!
    }
}
```